# How do I take input from a bootstrap search bar and put it into a ajax call to retrieve data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

Im using HTML, Javascript and bootstrap to build a web application and have hit a wall, I tried using `document.getElementById("input here")` but that just returned a array of 0. I want to take data from an api and then display it on a media list, im trying to use the search bar as a way of filtering the api GET with a key word as ive read this is possible in the api im using.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var word = document.getElementById("sbar");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://community-food2fork.p.mashape.com/search?key=0ee5a01caf7f7c3512b54978628f1a4e&q=' + word, // The URL to the API. You can get this in the API page of the API you intend to consume
            type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method, can be GET POST PUT DELETE etc
            data: {}, // Additional parameters here
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                search = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.recipes));
                console.dir(search);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization",   "KEY HERE");   // Enter here your Mashape key
            }
        });
    });
```

The HTML for the input:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="background: rgba(60, 255, 60, 0.2);" class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Meal Manager</h1>
        <p class="lead">A simple recipe app that provides ingerdiants fast.</p>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="sbar" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button" title="Search Database">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" title="Sort by reviews" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" title="Sort by trending" >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: if your `input` has `id="sbar"`, it should be: `document.getElementById("sbar").value` but if `document.getElementById("sbar")` returns an empty array, then your id is probably wrong... Can you edit to add some HTML too?

Comment: Just added it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost fine. HTML is missing some `div` closing and also your JS. *(At least the snippets you pasted here)*.

I've built this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jordinebot/4gagcpfd/) to test it and it works.

Just change:

```
url: 'https://…&q=' + word
```

to:

```
url: 'https://…&q=' + word.value
```

Your API call works and it's responding:

> {"message":"Invalid Mashape Key"}

which is totally logic since your need to replace the `"KEY HERE"` part for a real key. Check [Mashape Keys](http://docs.mashape.com/api-keys)

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "KEY HERE");
```

Comment: That worked thanks, Im going to try listing these in a bootstrap media list now, I took the Meshape key out before posting.